# How to calculate the sum of all connected nodes faster?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, traversal

There are N bidirectionally connected nodes (Pn), each node represents a value, and there is an attenuation value (0 - 1) between the nodes. Now I want to calculate the maximum value from each node to each node.
Each node is calculated only once.

Maybe I didn't express it well, I drew a picture
[image: Maybe I didn't express it well, I drew a picture]

I want to calculate the sum of the maximum value from each node to a node.

Then repeat to all nodes.

My first thought was brute force traversal, but I'd like to get a faster algorithm

Comment: Picture doesn't help either.

Comment: If the graph edges are bidirectional, shouldn't the max value from one node to the other infinite because two nodes can go back and forth each other to increase the travel distance? Is there a constraint that a node should be reached once?

Comment: @user58697 Sorry, I added more details

Comment: @taxevader sorry about that, I didn't express it completely. I Missed this condition -- “Each node is calculated only once”

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a bit non-trivial since both negated Dijkstra and Bellman-Ford algorithms can't be used in this case. I think one way to solve this problem is to use the [traveling salesman algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/traveling-salesman-problem-tsp-implementation/) but instead of finding the minimum path, you find the maximum and also keep track of the maximum distance from the starting point to other vertices (`distance` in the below code). The time complexity is O(n!) so it's pretty slow on larger graph. Let me know if you attempted a more efficient algorithm

```
from sys import maxsize
from itertools import permutations
 
# implementation of traveling Salesman Problem
def travellingSalesmanProblem(graph, s, distance):
 
    # store all vertex apart from source vertex
    vertex = []
    for i in range(len(graph)):
        if i != s:
            vertex.append(i)
 
    # store maximum weight Hamiltonian Cycle
    max_path = 0
    next_permutation=permutations(vertex)

    for i in next_permutation:
 
        # store current Path weight(cost)
        current_pathweight = 0
 
        # compute current path weight
        k = s
        for j in i:
            current_pathweight += graph[k][j]
            distance[s][j] = max(current_pathweight, distance[s][j])
            k = j
 
        # update minimum
        max_path = max(max_path, current_pathweight)
         
    return max_path, distance
 
 
# Driver Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    # matrix representation of graph
    graph = [[0, 10, 15, 20], [10, 0, 35, 25],
            [15, 35, 0, 30], [20, 25, 30, 0]]

    distance = [[0 for y in range(len(graph))] for x in range(len(graph))]
    for s in range(len(graph)):
        max_path, distance = travellingSalesmanProblem(graph, s, distance)
    
    print(distance)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code you gave does not seem to consider the condition of "each node is only calculated once"

Comment: @noodle_run I think it does take that into account because the permutations generating line  `next_permutation=permutations(vertex)` is essentially generating the paths to go through all the vertices from the starting point `s` and the generated paths can only have each vertex visited once. If you check the problem statement in traveling salesman algorithm link above, you will see that visiting each vertex once is part of the condition.